# How to replace default share options popup with a custom action sheet?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using the share api that react native offers by default.

I want to use a custom action sheet with sharing options instead of the default share popup that comes with react native share api.

[replace this default screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsDat.png)

[with something like this instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huJAA.png)

Answer (score 3):

Please check whether the below links satisfy your requirement. I think with Share API we can't control the apps shown in share popup dialog.

https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share

Comment: That's fine. i don't want to control the apps being shown in the share popup dialog. Just that I need to have a custom popup instead of the default one that comes with the api.